# Promise returned by vuex action does not have finally() method in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, promise, vuejs2, vuex

If I use one of my vuex actions in Chrome it always returns a Promise object having the methods `.catch()`, `.then()` and `.finally()`. If I do the same in Firefox(Version 60.0.2) I get a simple object (`{}`) having only the methods `.catch()` and `.then()` but not `.finally()`. Why do I not get a native Promise object but this pseudo object? This is especially bothersome because Firefox supports `finally()` since version 58.

actions.js

```
doBla: ({commit}) => {
    axios.post('http://test', {})
        .then(result => {
            commit('bla', result.data);
        });
}
```

test.vue

```
...
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['doBla']),
        test() {
            const r = this.doBla();
            console.log(r); // no function finally
            r.then(() => {
            })
            .finally(() => {}); // Crashes because of missing function in Firefox
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In FF 59 and 60, native Promise has `finally` method. Maybe something is overriding your Promise's interface?

Comment: As I said, it happens only for vuex actions under Firefox, but why?

Comment: Can you provide us a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Well its simply checking out the return value of calling a vuex action and compare the results between a current Firefox and Chrome browser. I will put some code up there :)

Comment: @jansolo you can get the equivalent of finally by putting a `.then` after your `.catch` i.e. `this.doBla().then().catch().then()` or if you have no `.catch`, add another `.then`

Comment: @m0meni Not the answer to the question but a good solution. Thank you.